# Why I cannot access my localhost:8888 address when a Jupyter notebook is active?

Tags: phpmyadmin, localhost, jupyter-notebook

I use phpMyAdmin regularly (via MAMP as I am a mac OSX user) to access a few databases that I have at my localhost. I never had a problem with it, until I started using Jupyter notebook (Anaconda distro).

The issue is that if I have a notebook active, then my browser cannot open the regular url 'http://localhost:8888/phpMyAdmin' and it shows a 404 message (with a jupyter logo)

The only way to regain access to phpMyAdmin is by killing the terminal window in which the jupyter process is called, and then localhost url is working again.

Strangely enough, MySQLWorkBench does work when Jupyter is active, and I am using this as temporary workaround, but I would like to understand what the source of conflict id between Jupyter and phpmyadmin, as I prefer to work in phpmyadmin (legacy and documentation reasons) without having to close my jupyter notebooks.

As additional info, there absolutely no problem in accessing the databases from jupyter  via the pymysql package.

Thanks!

**--EDIT--**

Thanks to Samuli's answer I understood the issue.
Both anaconda and Mamp have configured the same ports by default, 8888. WorkBench is smarter and if 8888 is used, it will use a different number.

Since I still want to launch Jupyter from anaconda, instead of using the terminal line proposed by the solution (which also works) I have reconfigured MAMP to use the Apache port 8890 (MAMP->Preferences->Ports)

Maybe other option would be o reconfigure Jupyter to open by default other port than 8888. For instance, in terminal:

:~jupyter notebook --generate-config
:~nano ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
and change the line 
*#c.NotebookApp.port = 8888* to 
c.NotebookApp.port = 8887

Comment: One little point of clarification to your edit is that since MySQL Workbench isn't accessed via a web browser, it doesn't bind to any port at all. It's an independent application that doesn't need a port, it's not that it's smarter or adapts to port 8888 being in use.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that phpMyAdmin and Jupyter Notebook are using the same port, namely 8888. Change the port Jupyter Notebook is using by starting it with following command and you should be able to use both without issues:
`jupyter notebook --port=8887`

Comment: Thanks, Samuli. I understood the issue and found a solution for my workflow.

Comment: Just a minor point of clarification to this, phpMyAdmin itself doesn't bind to a port, since it's accessed through your webserver it's actually the webserver binding to the port.